# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: php, android, android-volley

Here's my problem:

I am trying to get data from a server through PHP in android and whenever I try to do that, I get this error:

[  com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray  ]

I'm sure my code is correct because I tried using the data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/
and it worked.

I am using xampp server and using php for connecting.

here is my java code :

```
final String url1 = "http://192.168.0.101/deliveryApp/sellerProfile.php";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url1, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            Log.v("response is : ", String.valueOf(response));

            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length() ; i++){
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String tvfirstname = jsonObject.getString("firstname");
                    String tvlastname = jsonObject.getString("lastname");
                    String tvphonenumber = jsonObject.getString("email");
                    String tvemail = jsonObject.getString("phonenumber");

                    sellername.setText(tvfirstname +" "+ tvlastname);
                    selleremail.setText(tvemail+" ");
                    sellerphonenumber.setText(tvphonenumber+" ");

                }catch (JSONException e){

                }
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

my php script for this :

```
<?php
    $dbname = "delivery_app";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";

    $connection=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);

    session_start();
    $email = $_SESSION['tempemail'];
    //$email         = $_POST["email"];

    $querySellerProfile = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE email = '$email'";

    if($fetchresult = mysqli_query($connection,$querySellerProfile)){
        while ($response = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchresult)) {

            // echo $response['firstname'];
            // echo $response['lastname'];
            // echo $response['email'];
            // echo $response['phonenumber'];
            // echo $response['password'];

            $response2[] = $response;
        }

        echo json_encode($response2);

    }else{
        die("failed to get profile information");   
    } 

/*
    THIS CODE WILL RETRIEVE USER DATILS , AND ITS WORKING PERFECTLY
*/
?>
```

and the response from the server is :

```
[
  {
    "0": "2",
    "1": "testfname",
    "2": "testlname",
    "3": "testemail",
    "4": "9650684491",
    "5": "5555",
    "id": "2",
    "firstname": "testfname",
    "lastname": "testlname",
    "email": "testemail",
    "phonenumber": "9650684491",
    "password": "5555"
  }
]
```

I used POSTMAN app to check if my php is working or not, and it did.

I just can't find the problem with my code.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

JSONARRAY array=new JSONARRAY(response);

Then use array in for loop.

Comment: will you please elaborate ??